# reload content not form for dropdowns

Tags: javascript, html, forms, jquery

I am using a script to generate custom styled dropdowns out of my selects. Basically it creates a list out of the selects and hides the original select making it much easier to style than a `<select>` allows.

So the basic setup is like this

```
<div id="formdiv">
    <form method="get" name="search" action="samepage">
     inputs
    </form>
```

content from form

I want the wrap section to be generated without refreshing the form part that way the dropdodwns dont keep disappearing and reappearing when the page loads.

here is my code for creating the dropdowns ( any performance tuning suggestions are welcome :) )

```
function createDropDown() { 
                        var selects = $("select.createdrop"); 
                        var idCounter = 1; 
                        selects.each(function() { 
                          var dropID = "dropdown_" + idCounter; 
                          var source = $(this);
                          var selected = source.find("option[selected]"); 
                          var options = $("option", source);
                          source.after('<dl id="' + dropID + '" class="dropdown"></dl>'); 
                          var imgtype = '<img src="images/transpx.gif" class="srcimg '+selected.text().toLowerCase()+'" />'
                          $("#" + dropID).append('<dt><a href="#">'+imgtype + selected.text() + '<span class="value">' + selected.val() + '</span><img src="images/select-down-arrow.png" class="down-arrow" /></a></dt>'); 
                          $("#" + dropID).append('<dd><ul></ul></dd>'); 
                          options.each(function() { 
                            $imgclasstxt = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                            var srcimg = '<img src="images/transpx.gif" class="srcimg '+$imgclasstxt+'" width="10px"/>';
                            $("#" + dropID + " dd ul").append('<li><a href="#" id="'+$(this).text()+'">'+srcimg + $(this).text() + '<span class="value">' + $(this).val() + '</span></a></li>'); 
                          }); 
                          idCounter++; 
                        }); 
                      }
```

and here is the code for selecting an option and submiting the form

```
$(".dropdown dd ul a").click(function() { 
                          var dl = $(this).closest("dl"); 
                          var dropID = dl.attr("id"); 
                          var text = $(this).attr("id");
                          var source = dl.prev(); 
                          var typeicon = '<img src="images/transpx.gif" class="srcimg '+text.toLowerCase()+'" />'
                          $("#" + dropID + " dt a").html(typeicon+''+text+'<img src="images/select-down-arrow.png" class="down-arrow" />'); 
                          $("#" + dropID + " dd ul").hide(); 
                          var value = $(this).children("span.value").html();
                          source.val(value);
                          $(this).addClass('selected');
                          $('body').css('cursor','wait');
                          document.search.submit();
                        });
```

Comment: is there nothing that I can do to speed up this form or should I just look into rolling my own which would set me back like 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're modifying the DOM a lot with this code.  If it's slow, try dropping as many DOM changes as possible into a string first and then inserting it.  You're also doing repeat selects in some places.  Example:

```
$("#" + dropID).append('<dt><a href="#">'+imgtype + selected.text() + '<span class="value">' + selected.val() + '</span><img src="images/select-down-arrow.png" class="down-arrow" /></a></dt>'); 
    $("#" + dropID).append('<dd><ul></ul></dd>');
```

Could change to:

```
var html = '<dt><a href="#">'+imgtype + selected.text() + '<span class="value">' + selected.val() + '</span><img src="images/select-down-arrow.png" class="down-arrow" /></a></dt><dd><ul></ul></dd>'
$("#" + dropID).append(html);
```